Modify cells in tbl_summary table by dividing with constant
I have a table which has n and percentages in cells. I would like to divide or multiply each n by a constant, ideally while creating the table.
library(gtsummary)
df <- data.frame(
  a=sample(1:4, 10, replace=T),
  b=sample(1:4, 10, replace=T),
  c=sample(1:4, 10, replace=T)
)
df %>%
  tbl_summary()


For example, instead of the first entry being 5 (50%), I would like to divide each n by 10, leading to .5 (50%).
I've tried 1) modifying the table's data with regular expressions which seems quite involved, and 2) playing unsuccessfully with the statistic term in tbl_summary. I would appreciate any suggestions.

your regex approach is pretty straightforward with the example data you provide. Is it too complicated for your actual real problem dataset?

You were concerned about the complexity of your regex approach, but you can do fairly easily with:
ts = tbl_summary(df)


ts$table_body <- ts$table_body %>% 
  mutate(stat_0 = stringr::str_replace(stat_0,"^\\d+",\(x) as.numeric(x)/10))

Then ts renders as:


Any advice on how to change the header N?

You can use modify_table_body to do this while creating the table. You could also set up functions to use.
constant <- 10
divide <- \(x,y) x/y
multiply <- \(x,y) x*y

t1 <- df %>%
  tbl_summary() |>
  modify_table_body(~ .x %>%
          mutate(
            stat_0=stringr::str_replace(stat_0,"^\\d+", \(x) 
                            do.call(divide, 
                                    list(as.numeric(x), constant)))))

t2 <- df %>%
  tbl_summary() |>
  modify_table_body(~ .x %>%
          mutate(
            stat_0=stringr::str_replace(stat_0, "^\\d+", \(x) 
                            do.call(multiply, 
                                    list(as.numeric(x), constant)))))

tbl_merge(list(t1, t2),
          tab_spanner = c("**Divide**", "**Multiply**"))



You could also do it this way:
FUN <- '/'
constant <- 10

df %>%
  tbl_summary() |>
  modify_table_body(~ .x %>%
                      mutate(
                        stat_0=stringr::str_replace(stat_0, "^\\d+", \(x) 
                                  do.call(FUN, list(as.numeric(x), constant))
                                         ) ) )

